# Creating a list to dynamically allocate objects in C++ based on user input

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been trying to find a tutorial or an example of how could I create a new object of a class based on user input.

To exemplify I'd like to give the user the option to press the key '1' to create a new object of a class "Customer" and add the customer information as name, ID, etc.
And then access it through the customer name or ID to show all information stored in that object.

My biggest struggle is how to create multiple objects and allocate it in a list I can't find any online tutorial on this.

***EDIT***

Thanks to everyone who helped on this.

I've tried to implement the code below but no luck:

```
do
{
    cout << "Press 1 to create a new customer";
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 1:
        cout << "Input Customer's name";
        cin >> tempName;
        customer *tempName = new customer();
        tempName -> name = tempName;

    }
} while (opt !=9);
```

Error: invalid conversion from 'Customer' to 'char'

What I had in my mind is to receive a customer name from user and then create an object of type customer with the same name as the customer, and then after that add more info. After I accomplish this I'll look for adding the object address to a vector or list.

I'd appreciate any help on how could I accomplish this first goal.

Comment: Do you know how to read input from a user using `std::cin`? Do you know how to create objects from a class? Do you know how to add objects to a `std::vector`? Then you already know all you need to know, just put it all together.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the exact problem you're facing? Your problem, as you currently describe, seems to boil down to just writing an if-condition checking for user input and creating an object (dynamically) and storing the pointer to the object in a container (preferably `std::vector`).

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using, all of them should have plenty of examples of doing exactly that?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I've just updated my question in order to try to be more specific of what I'm struggling at the moment.

@SamVarshavchik I'm looking more for online information and videos to learn and couldn't find this topic online. I've been searching for "list multiple objects c++" and simillar

Comment: Dear Sam, I really appreciate your words and honesty on this. I'll now use C++ Primer fifth edition to guide my study. Thanks for the advice. Please let me know what you think about this book and if you know any other textbook which could be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you are looking for is called *factory* or *abstract factory*. You do not know in advance, what object shall be created. So, the user will input some number, and, dependent on that, you will add the corresponding object and set its parameters.

Of course, all possible different classes need to be defined before in your code, but they will be created and instantiated **late**, at runtime, **dynamically**.

For this, usually a `std::map` or `std::unordered` map ist used. In the key-part, you will store a selector. In your case, the user will enter a number, like 1 or 2 or 3 and so on. In the value-part of the map, you will store a function pointer to a create function.

The create function will then dynamically create an object, *late*, during runtime. And because the signature of the create function (especially the return value) must be of the same type, we will use polymorphism, and derive all your needed classes from a common base class.

We can then store all objects as a pointer to the base class in a container, and call member functions through their base class pointer.

This is the general concept. Often the constructor for the derived classes shall be different, because you want to pass a set of certain parameters for each class. Then it gets more complicated. But can also be solved:

Please see the, sorry for that, somehow more complex solution example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Define the factory with an initializer list
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };

    // Add a new entry for the factory
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```

The create function can be called with your selector and with different parameters.

Calling the `print` function through the base class pointer, will always call the correct function.

Please read about the factory pattern to get a better underdtanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::any` to do what I think you want to do

```
void add_item(std::list<std::any>& list) {
    int t = get_type_from_user();
    
    if (t == 1) {
        Customer c = create_customer_from_user();
        list.push_back(std::any(c));
    } else if (t == 2) {
        //insert other type into list
    }
}

Customer get_customer_from_id(const std::list<std::any>& list, int id) {
    for (const auto& entry : list) {
        if (entry.type() == typeid(Customer)) {
            auto c = std::any_cast<Customer>(entry);
            if (c.id() == id)
                return c;
        }
    }

    throw CustomerNotFound();
}
```

If you don't need it to be a `std::list` a `std::vector` would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact type of `customer` lets say it's something like this:

```
class customer
{
public:
    customer() { }

    std::string name;
};
```

Then my suggestion is to modify it so you hide the data members, and initialize them using the constructor:

```
class customer
{
public:
    customer(std::string const& name)
        : name(name)
    { }

private:
    std::string name;
};
```

Then you can use a `std::vector<customer>` and create as many as you need in a loop:

```
std::vector<customer> customers;

// Example loop, just to show how to add objects to the vector
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter name of customer #" << i + 1 << ": ";

    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;

    customers.emplace_back(name);
}
```

After this loop there will be ten `customer` objects in the vector, each with their own respective name.

---

And to be brutally honest, any decent book or class should have taught you this.